# Are WGS84 LatLon coordinates and EGM96 LatLon coordinates the same and difference for [LatLonEle] is elevation only?

Tags: coordinate-system, elevation, wgs84, egm96

Does WGS84 LatLon coordinates and EGM96 LatLon coordinates are the same?

Is difference for [Lat;Lon;Ele] is in elevation only?

If I have, for example, a [Lat;Lon] point in WGS84, I can take elevation from NASADEM_HGT.001 dataset (which is in EGM96) without any conversion of Lat\Lon and this will be accurate elevation for this point in EGM96. By adding calculated undulation for [Lat;Lon], I can find WGS84 Elevation.

Am I correct ?

How can I 'proof' that to myself? Any docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the CRS in `pyproj` for `EGM96` it appears to be a Vertical CRS only.

```py
>>> from pyproj import CRS
>>> CRS("EGM96")
<Vertical CRS: EPSG:5773>
Name: EGM96 height
Axis Info [vertical]:
- H[up]: Gravity-related height (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Datum: EGM96 geoid
- Ellipsoid: undefined
- Prime Meridian: undefined
```

Based on the NGA docs: https://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/wgs84/gravitymod/egm96/intpthel.html

```
Geoid heights can be used to convert between orthometric heights (approximately mean sea level) and ellipsoid heights according to the formula:
h   =   H   +   N
Where,
h = WGS 84 Ellipsoid height
H = Orthometric height
N = EGM96 Geoid height

Note that EGM96 applies only to the WGS 84 reference ellipsoid.
```

From this, it appears that EGM96 a geoid model that can be applied to WGS84.

Also related: [How does a Spatial Reference System like WGS84 have an elipsoid and a geoid?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214780/how-does-a-spatial-reference-system-like-wgs84-have-an-elipsoid-and-a-geoid)